# jquery: Confused about the behavior of animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jquery code that animates an element via a while loop which increments a counter and repeatedly call animate() :

```
$("#right").click(function () {
    $i = 1;
    $ii = 10
    while ($i < 250) {
        console.log($i);
        $("#content").animate({
            "left": "+=" + $ii + "px"
        },
            "fast");

        $i += $ii;
        console.log($i);

        if ($i > 250) {
            alert("I am an alert box!");
        }
    }
});
```

What I don't understand is that it seems like the while loop completes immediately and *then* animate() runs because when the function gets called console.log() immediately writes all iterations of the counter to the console, the alert pops and then the element moves. Why is this and how can I check for when animate() is finished?

Comment: Look up the term "asynchronous"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand well what you are trying to do, but the while loop will always be completed immediately.

You can check when animate is finished like this:

```
$("#content").animate({

},"fast",function(){
   alert('completed')
});
```

Anyway, i think your animate function is not going to work well. If you want to increment the "#content" left position, you'll have to get this info like this `$("#content").position().left`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback that is called when the animation is complete.

More info [here](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete).